# Create-react-app is not creating app and throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cmd

I have just started learning react but this error is coming in my way. I have installed node.js latest version `14.6.0` and it has installed successfully. The npm is also installed with version `6.14.6` But Every time I use npm on command prompt it shows like this.

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

But that's not the problem, it stills work somehow I don't know. By this I have installed `create-react-app`. I have installed it by every single old or latest method(on their github) and it installs too and version is `3.4.1`. Now problem starts from here and I have tried every method for it to resolve. I have changed PATH (which I didn't need to because paths were perfect). Error it throws is:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\HUZAIFA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
  spawnargs: [
    '/d',
    '/s',
    '/c',
    '"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'
  ]
}
```

It creates the file with package.json in it only. Now I have been hitting my head for almost 4 or 5 hours  but it isn't working. `npm.cmd` in the nodejs folder does not open. And There are many other issues with it or they are issues or not. I don't know yet but kindly help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "%SystemRoot%\system32" to path variable in environment variables

Comment: Never-mind. I just installed windows again and it worked. :)

Comment: Old way of removing virus ;)

Comment: It was just issue of environment variable. (adding Path in environment variable)